# Use AsyncLayoutInflater with DataBinding

Tags: android, asynchronous, layout-inflater, android-databinding

I currently inflate most of my layouts using the [`DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, parent, attachToParent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) method.

But I saw that their is an [`AsyncLayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater.html) since `Support Library revision 24` that allow the inflation to occur on a separate thread. I would like to use this mechanism in some part of my app but I don't want to drop the use of `databinding` for that.

`DataBindingUtil` doesn't contain any method like `inflateAsync()`. But is it plan to add a support for that? Or is their a way to combine both the [`AsyncLayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater.html) and the use of `databinding`?

I tried to use the [`AsyncLayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater.html) inside the `inflate` method of `DataBindingUtil` but actually [`AsyncLayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater.html) is not a subclass of the original `LayoutInflater`.

Thank's for reading!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use [`DataBindingUtil.bind(view)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#bind(android.view.View)) to bind to the root of the inflated layout.

```
new AsyncLayoutInflater(this).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInflateFinished(@NonNull View view, int resid, @Nullable ViewGroup parent) {
        MyLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use the `AsyncLayoutInflater` with data binding, but my question would be, is it actually useful? Inflating a layout asynchronously can have its advantages, but if you're working with data binding, you run the risk of the view not being inflated when you attempt to bind data to the views, as there is no method such as `waitForBinding()`.

Comment: yes its pretty useful when you build complex UI you would not appreciate it if you only build simple UI. You can pretty much make a simple loading ui while the complex ui is loading asynchronously.